# Error when installing gensim using pip install

Tags: python, gensim

Used command `pip install --upgrade gensim` from https://pypi.org/project/gensim/
Anyone knows what might cause this?

````
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gensim
  Running setup.py clean for gensim
Failed to build gensim
Installing collected packages: gensim
    Running setup.py install for gensim ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Andreea Elena\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pipinstall-khjrriwd\\gensim_18d18388d198487b8f7aebdfc3c97b94\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-khjrriwd\\gensim_18d18388d198487b8f7aebdfc3c97b94\\stup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c7348b68\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Iclude\gensim'```
````

Comment: Try running it without the `--upgrade` argument, just `pip install gensim`.

Answer (score 6):

It was a version problem, python 3.9 won't work with gensim. Installed 3.8 and works now.