# Unable to install Summertime in Google Colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, summarization

I'm trying to install the [Summertime library](https://github.com/Yale-LILY/SummerTime) in a [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19tPdBgaJ4_QjSiFyoxtpnFGW4OG1gTec?usp=sharing) that is provided within the repo to play around.

However, during the installation process of Summertime I've been encountering issues which seem to prematurely end the installation and either not install the library at all or don't install some modules for some reason (which then makes it impossible to use methods down the line as I keep getting missing module errors).

Here's an example of an error message I'm getting:

```
Obtaining file:///content/SummerTime
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from summertime==1.2.1) (0.29.35)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from summertime==1.2.1) (1.22.4)
Collecting click==7.1.2 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 82.8/82.8 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting transformers~=4.5.1 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading transformers-4.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 27.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting torch~=1.8 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading torch-1.13.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (887.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 887.5/887.5 MB 1.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting lexrank~=0.1.0 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading lexrank-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 69.8/69.8 kB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nltk==3.6.2 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading nltk-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.5/1.5 MB 70.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting spacy==3.0.6 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading spacy-3.0.6.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.1/7.1 MB 81.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pytextrank (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading pytextrank-3.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting datasets~=1.6.2 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading datasets-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.8/221.8 kB 18.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting sentencepiece~=0.1.95 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading sentencepiece-0.1.99-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/1.3 MB 45.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting summ-eval==0.70 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading summ_eval-0.70-py3-none-any.whl (62.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.5/62.5 MB 9.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting jupyter (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
Collecting gdown~=4.2.0 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading gdown-4.2.2.tar.gz (13 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting readability-lxml (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading readability_lxml-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from summertime==1.2.1) (4.11.2)
Collecting orjson (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading orjson-3.9.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (138 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 138.7/138.7 kB 14.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting gensim~=3.8.3 (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading gensim-3.8.3.tar.gz (23.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.4/23.4 MB 61.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting sklearn (from summertime==1.2.1)
  Downloading sklearn-0.0.post5.tar.gz (3.7 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Additionally, yesterday I've been getting errors with building wheels for gensim & tokenizers modules.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Tried installing missing modules manually using `pip install`. Well, bad idea & it also didn't work out as at some point some module did not want to get installed (don't remember exactly which one it was, will try to replicate).
2. Tried downgrading current Python version (3.10) to 3.8 using the instructions from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/zc4cx8/how_to_downgrade_python_3815_onto_python_37_on/). This was based on possible solutions found in these posts: [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958119/error-when-installing-gensim-using-pip-install), [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70751892/error-in-pip-install-transformers-building-wheel-for-tokenizers-pyproject-toml) and [Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595700/could-not-build-wheels-for-tokenizers-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject-to)
3. Reset & deleted the runtime and started from scratch multiple times. Tried running the same installation cell multiple times as well.
4. Followed both installation instructions provided in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Yale-LILY/SummerTime).

I'm not sure what I'm missing here and why is installing SummerTime so hard. I'd appreciate if anyone can point out what the issue could be. Thanks!